# NodeJS Api gives Internal Server Error on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api, express, aws-lambda

I have developed a serverless API that works well on serverless-offline. It returns the rows from AWS RDS DB. But when same is deployed on AWS Lambda the route gives me internal server error. I have tried:

1. Have done the deploy API for my gateway.
2. Have also returned status for success calls.

Below is my code:

app.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
const client = require('./connection.js')


client.connect();
app.get('/',  (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to API that helps connect with Recruitment DB')
})

app.get('/users', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const allProfiles = await client.query("SELECT * FROM public.portal_users");
        res.status(200).send(allProfiles.rows);  
      } catch (error) {
          res.status(500).send("Error received: "+ error.message);
      }

  })

module.exports = app
```

serverless.yml file:

```
service: portalserver

frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  memorySize: 2048
  stage: dev
  timeout: 15
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: ap-south-1

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http: 
          path: /
          method: get
          cors: true
      - http: 
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: any
          cors: true


plugins:
  - serverless-offline

custom:
  serverless-offline:
    noPrependStageInUrl: true
```

The get / works well but /users return Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem was related to access. I created a VPC for my lambda function to access the secured AWS RDS DB and it worked.